# COMPRESS operates in a different way (proc sql and step data)

Tags: sas

I am working is SAS guide 7.1 and I need to run a process with proc sql but don't work well, though it work well with step data.
The folliwing code replicate the issue

```
data test;
input date;
datalines;
20140101
;
run;

data test2;
set test;
date1 = input(compress(date),yymmdd10.);
format date1 date9.;
run;
```

The output
[image]

Code with proc sql:

```
proc sql;
    create table test3 as select
         *,
    input(compress(date),yymmdd10.) format date9. as date1
from test;
quit;
```

The error message:

Function COMPRESS requires a character expression as argument 1.
Why COMPRESS operates in a different way with both step data and proc sql?

Comment: Because data step converts it to the format as the function requires. Try doing the same in `if` subsetting, and `proc sql` `where` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compress()` function is operating the same way.

But `PROC SQL` does not do automatic type conversion the way that a data step will.  Look at the notes from your data step.

```
207  data test2;
208  set test;
209  date1 = input(compress(date),yymmdd10.);
210  format date1 date9.;
211  run;

NOTE: Numeric values have been converted to character values at the places given by:
      (Line):(Column).
      209:24
```

Just tell SAS explicitly that you want to convert the number 20,140,101 to the string '20140101' and then convert that string into a date value.

```
input(put(date,z8.),yymmdd8.)
```

Comment: Or read it from the `datalines` as $8., i.e. `input date $8.;`